# Bazel: Replace includes when building for testing purposes

Tags: build, include, bazel

I have a Module A, that includes some sort of hardware specific header file Io.h. Now I have a different Module B, that depends on A, but wants to replace the header file Io.h that is needed by Module A with a stubbed one, located in the package directory B.

Is there any way to "overwrite" the dependency of A onto Io.h to use the one given by Module B?

```
WORKSPACE
|
|-A
|--A.c
|--Io.h
|-B
|--B.c
|--Io.h
```

I understand, that in this case I should probably generate two targets of A, once for depending on the local Io.h and one for depending on the Io.h from B. However, if the dependency onto Io.h is nested deeply in the dependencys of A instead of being included directly, I would have to change every intermediate dependency as well. That is nothing I want to do or can do.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using a [select](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select) function in the target rule of B:
If a specific [config setting](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#config_setting) is fulfilled, the Io.h gets replaced:

In A/BUILD

```
cc_library(
  name="StubLib",
  hdrs=["Io.h"],
  visibility=["["//visibility:public"],
)
```

In B/BUILD

```
cc_library(
  name="B",
  srcs=["B.c"],
  hdrs=["B.c"],
  deps=select({
       "//conditions:default":[":io_h"],
       "//custom_config":["//A:StubLib"],
       }),
  visibility=["["//visibility:public"],
)
cc_library(
  name="io_h",
  hdrs=["Io.h"],
)
```